# Codeigniter Always append something for all send request

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, xmlhttprequest

I am finding for a good solution in codeigniter in where for every post request are made I would append something in it.

My temporary solution is to create a library and if post is found I would append something like this in my URI ?sTime=20140623101010 but this is dynamic which is basically bypassing the cache gateway that is setted in my server.

Any bright ideas that can lighten me up on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need this always append option ? 
If its for protection or something like that, at latest versions of Codeigniter there is CSRF token .. If you are generating forms with CI form helper you can just activate that from the config and your forms will be protected..

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve -> posted data can be turned into an array and then you can just push an item to the end of it - is that what you mean? Kind of need the purpose to know how best to advise!

Comment: @Svetlio no it's not for protection but like what I had said I want to bypass our cache gateway, so lets say if you keep sending the same request, the server will get the cached request , so inorder to bypass this I need to add a time parameter for request to treat as a unique.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Something in your logic is not right.. 
Do you need it for GET requests or for POST requests ? 
Because if its a POST there is no logic to get the same POST data multiple times.. And if it is a GET you can cache any result after the 1st request for XX time (deleting it if there is need)..
Passing such time field won't help you with anything :) And I wonder, why you are not using some SESSION field for your idea? What will help you that time field..

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Codeigniter support it you can use CSRF protection to stop users reposting the same form more than once.. [CI documentation Security](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html) ( if this is your problem.. )

If you want it for other reason there are different ways to create such "time" value.

Best way is to change the CI form Helper function form_open. Inside you can put what ever field you want and after that you have only to use this function when starting new form. [CI documentation extending CI Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use before any function in your controller

```
if(!$this->input->get('time') && empty($this->input->post()))

{

redirect($url.'?time='.time());

}
```

Comment: or just put this in constructor no need to put any every function

Comment: ... 1 big minus.. 
Think what will do a redirect if you are submitting POST Form ?

Comment: really well spotted @Svetlio , thanks a lot for it. +1